# how to build a mobile application created with ionic and laravel?

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, build, hosting, publish

I have developed an application using ionic for the frontend and laravel for the backend ... now I wish I could see it running on my phone, but I don't know what I need to buy as hosting and database, which files should I upload etc ... any help?

php version: 7.4.1
laravel framework: 8.78.1
phpmyadmin: 5.0.1
mariaDB: 10.4.11
mysql: 7.4.1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see two questions:

1. How to try the app on your phone:
   When you build an App, you can read [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/deploying-mobile) about how to deploy it to your phone by e.g. transferring an APK to your Android phone. To install the APK, you have to enable the developer-features in your phone's settings.
2. How to host the Laravel backend (to try it with your app):
   You could use your local development environment. E.g. when your laptop with your laravel backend running and your phone are in the same Wifi-Network, you just need to expose the project to the network so that the app on you phone can reach it.

Hosting it on a public server would require you to have a domain. The server has to meet the needs of your project. You have to look for the correct php-version, php extensions, etc ([Laravel Docs on Server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#server-requirements)). For a small project, most shared-hosting servers with ssh-access and MySql database would fit. You could put some more effort by choosing a server from digital ocean, where a droplet is just a few bucks but you have to do all the configuration by yourself.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For running it on mobile you could use capacitor with ionic [Capacitor](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj7wYeMkKr5AhWni_0HHWHMCT8QFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcapacitorjs.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw1hSqOQB8vOEpESk-Al3Fyy)